# Prove that $ f(z) = \sum\limits_{n\ge1}\frac{z^n}{n^2}$ is univalent in the disk $\,D\big(\frac23\big)$

Tags: complex-analysis, power-series, analyticity

I'm having some difficulty with this question:

> *Prove that the function 
>   $\,\,\displaystyle f(z) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{z^n}{n^2}\,$ 
>   is univalent in the disk $D\left(\dfrac23\right)$.*

There is the following hint: 
$\dfrac{z^n-w^n}{z-w} = z^{n-1} + wz^{n-2} + ... + w^{n-2}z + w^{n-1}.$

Any ideas?

Comment: I've always wondered why *injective* is called *univalent* in the context of complex analysis... It's probably by historical reasons, but still...

Comment: @lhf Probably because complex analysis came before set theory. And remember the old usage *integral function* to mean *entire function*. And the *analytic* vs. *holomorphic* debate, which isn't really resolved (probably because it doesn't actually matter).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assume that $f(z)=f(w)$, for $z\ne w$ and  $\lvert z\rvert,\,\lvert w\rvert<\frac23$.
Then
$$
0=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{z^n-w^n}{n^2}=(z-w)\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{z^{n-1+}z^{n-2}w+\cdots+w^{n-1}}{n^2}.
$$
Hence
$$
0=1+\sum_{n=2}^\infty\frac{z^{n-1+}z^{n-2}w+\cdots+w^{n-1}}{n^2}.
$$
But
$$
\sum_{n=2}^\infty\frac{\lvert z^{n-1+}z^{n-2}w+\cdots+w^{n-1}\rvert}{n^2}\le
\sum_{n=2}^\infty\frac{n(2/3)^{n-1}}{n^2}=\sum_{n=2}^\infty\frac{(2/3)^{n-1}}{n}=-\frac{3}{2}\big(1+\ln (1-2/3)\big)<1.
$$
Since, for $0<\lvert x\rvert<1$,
$$
\sum_{n=2}^\infty\frac{x^{n-1}}{n}=\frac{1}{x}\left(\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{x^{n}}{n}-1\right)=\frac{1}{x}(-\ln(1-x)-1).
$$
Note. This $f$ is univalent even in $D\big(\frac{5}{6}\big)$.

Comment: Could also estimate $$\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}(2/3)^{n-1}/n < (2/3)/2 + (1/3)(2/3)^2\cdot 1/(1-2/3) = 7/9.$$